# Pass props to child components after Async update

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The updated props after async operation has to be passed to Inputs component. How to pass the props to child component after the async operation is completed.

I'm trying without connect in the Child  component. Is this possible

```
class SignUp extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
   this.props.UserSignupType();
  }
  render(){
    <Inputs {...this.props} >
  }
}

const stateToProps = state => ({
  signupInputs: state.signupInputs
});

connect(stateToProps, null)(SignUp);

class Inputs extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {...props};
  }
  render(){
    if(!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return <Loading />
    } else {
      let inputs = [];
      this.state.inputs.forEach(function(input){
        inputs.push(<TextField value={input.text}>)
      });
      return <View>{inputs}</View>
    }
  }
}
```

Update after @Adam answer:

Note: I have tried with this.state.isLoaded and this.props.isLoaded. Using both approach i'm unable to get the data

Update 2:

```
class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {...props};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
   this.props.UserSignupType();
  }
  render(){
    <Inputs {...this.state} >
  }
}

const stateToProps = state => ({
  signupInputs: state.signupInputs
});

connect(stateToProps, null)(SignUp);

class Inputs extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {...props};
  }
  render(){
    if(!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return <Loading />
    } else {
      let inputs = [];
      this.state.inputs.forEach(function(input){
        inputs.push(<TextField value={input.text}>)
      });
      return <View>{inputs}</View>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

You don't need to connect your child component to the redux store. You are passing your props down to the child, but your problem is that in the constructor of your child you are putting these props into the state and then discarding them. Thus any subsequent changes to the props of the parent will *not* propagate to the child.

In your child you should be doing `if(!this.props.isLoaded)` instead of `if(!this.state.isLoaded)`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry i need to edit my question, i'm doing with props only. I'm sorry @Adam

Comment: You should still be using this.props instead of this.state. Since your child doesn't modify the loaded state variable you can just check this from the props. Also, your parent component doesn't seem to be loading the `isLoaded` variable into it's props, check your `mapStateToProps` method.

Comment: The data is updated in parent props after the async call but not in child props

Comment: If you are using the props in the child I see no reason why it wouldn't work, with the code you have provided. Maybe you need to update your code snippet, but you shouldn't be storing your props in the state and instead just use them directly from `this.props` as I suggested earlier.

Comment: Yours works thank you, I'm updating my question can you help me with that