# Async update parent props to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to send updated props of parent component to child component after async operation. Is there any lifecycle method available

```
 class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {...props};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
   this.props.UserSignupType();
  }
  render(){
    <Inputs {...this.state} >
  }
}

const stateToProps = state => ({
  signupInputs: state.signupInputs
});

connect(stateToProps, null)(SignUp);

class Inputs extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {...props};
  }
  render(){
    if(!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return <Loading />
    } else {
      let inputs = [];
      this.state.inputs.forEach(function(input){
        inputs.push(<TextField value={input.text}>)
      });
      return <View>{inputs}</View>
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Possible duplicate of [Pass props to child components after Async update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931613/pass-props-to-child-components-after-async-update/50931768?noredirect=1#comment88862970_50931768)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First correction: You do not need to add data in state from props if you are not updating it. Also if you are updating it, it should be in state of the child component. So parent component can directly pass props to child component like this:

```
<Inputs {...this.props} >
```

Now in `Inputs` component you can directly use `props` if it's not going to change or you can add it to state using `componentWillReceiveProps` function as shown below:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   this.setState({...nextProps});
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to add some more functions along with the props data and send to child, because the onchange has to reflected in more than one child components

Comment: Then you can pass like `<Inputs {...this.props}  someFunc1={this.someFunc1} someFunc2={this.someFunc2}>`. Also if there is a requirement in parent component than you can set props to state as shown in answer.

Comment: Yes, it can be done but as per your answer componentWillReceiveProps will be deprecated in the future and it often leads to bugs and inconsistencies (according to the react docs, i'm not pro on react). https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: It's depends on which react version are you using. If you are directly using v16.4 then you can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` in place of `componentWillReceiveProps` and there you need to return an state object in stead of calling setState. And for react version less than v16.4 you should use `componentWillReceiveProps` only.

Answer (score 0):

The state can be updated via getDerivedStateFromProps.
Its a static method, where you can compare the state and the new props and update the state.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
// Store myId in state.
if (nextProps.myId !== prevState.myId) {
  // this updates the state
  return {
    myId: nextProps.myId
  };
}

// This implies it won't update the state
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to set the state of the child component to the props received? I would just use the props directly.

In your case I am not sure that the constructor gets called on refresh, thus the state of the child component does not get updated. Try using the props directly.

Comment: Hi, I need to add some more functions along with the props data and send to child, because the onchange has to reflected in more than one child components

Comment: That's fine, but I still don't find a reason why you need a state inside the child. I don't see the child props modified somewhere in the example code. Modifying them in the parent is fine though.